# XSLT : storing accumulated values in array like structures

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

PFB input xml and the desired output.

**InputXML**

```
 <Shipment xmlns="http://www.example.org">
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C1</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C2</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>8</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C3</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
</Shipment>
```

**DesiredOutput**

```
<Shipment xmlns="http://www.example.org"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org>
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C1</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C2</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>6</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>8</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>6</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C3</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
</Shipment>
```

For every container, check for every PackedItem, if the quantity (in the current container ->PackedItem) is equal to the "Total" element in any of the preceding siblings

```
if yes; Total= Quantity     
else; Total=Total+quantity //total is initially 0
```

Applied to sample XML, it means:

1. We have to compare the quantity in every PackedItem to each of the preceding siblings "Total" value. If the quantity is not equal to any of the precding totals then we will consider it as a parameter to form the total for that particular container.

   For example: if you see the first container , the value of total for the first container would be 8 (sum both quantites simply as there are no preceding siblings).
2. For the second container, we pick the first quantity that is 4 and check if it is equal to preceding siblings sum (which was 8). Since it is not equal it would be considered to form the sum. Moving further in the second conatiner we will not consider 8 (quantity for second item) as it is eual to previous conatiners sum.

   The third quantity 2 is unique (not equal to preceding siblings sum ) hence would be considered to form the sum. Hence the final total for the second container would be 4+2=6.

So the value 6 is populated for items (which had unique quantities) in the "Total" element. So the total 6 is populated in 1st and 3rd packed items within the second container.

Run a loop for rest of the PackedItem in the container, compare every quantity in a container with the total accumlated in previous containers. If we have a new value for Quantity which has not come in any of the preceding siblings "Total" element add that value to the sum and populate the final value in the "Total" element for the current container

If there are no preceding siblings then simply add all the quantities in the PackedItems and update the final value in the "Total" element. Please refer to the DesiredOutput sample attached below.

My issue is that if I have to populate the "Total" for the fourth container,I have to calculate and then compare the Total from all the three previous containers. I should not have to calculate the Total values every time. I am looking for a way to calculate and store these values in an array like structure and be able to refer them for comparing each quantity in a Packeditem to every value of Total in the preceding sibling.

Or another option that I was looking for is - if there is a way to read the accumlated values from the target tree structure. So I could read what was accumlated in the "Total" element for the previous containers.

PFB part of the XSLT (version 1.0) that I am working on

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Total')]">
        <xsl:variable name="ContainerID" select="../../ns0:ContainerID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ItemID" select="../ns0:ItemID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Quantity" select="../ns0:Quantity"/>
        <xsl:element name="Total" namespace="http://www.example.org">
            <xsl:call-template name="Add">
                <xsl:with-param name="ContainerID" select="$ContainerID"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="ItemID" select="$ItemID"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Quantity" select="$Quantity"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Add">
        <xsl:param name="ContainerID" select="$ContainerID"/>
        <xsl:param name="ItemID"/>
        <xsl:param name="Quantity"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- when there are no preceding siblings. this is the first container-->
            <xsl:when test="not(/ns0:Shipment/ns0:Container[./ns0:ContainerID=$ContainerID]/preceding-sibling::ns0:Container/ns0:PackedItem[./ns0:ItemID=$ItemID])">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(/ns0:Shipment/ns0:Container[./ns0:ContainerID=$ContainerID]/ns0:PackedItem[./ns0:ItemID=$ItemID]/ns0:Quantity)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- check the total value in preceding siblings and compare them to each quantity in this container -->
            <!-- problem: reading the accumulated value in Total for preceding containers. -->
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Any pointers/suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: If I understand well, we have to compute first some totals, and process again this data to set the Total to a final value for each - am I right? However: 1) I don't see any *Total* in the container in your desired output 2) I don't see any fourth Container

Comment: 1)We have to compare the quantity in every PackedItem to each of the preceding siblings "Total" value. If the quantity is not equal to any of the precding totals then we will consider it as a parameter to form the total for that particular container.

Comment: For.example: if you see the first container , the value of total for the first container would be 8 (sum both quantites simply as there are no preceding siblings).

Comment: For the second container, we pick the first quantity that is 4 and check if it is equal to preceding sibling`s sum (which was 8). Since it is not equal it would be considered to form the sum. Moving further in the second conatiner we will not consider 8 (quantity for second item) as it is eual to previous conatiner`s sum. The third quantity 2 is unique (not equal to preceding siblings sum ) hence would be considered to form the sum. Hence the final total for the second container would be 4+2=6.

Comment: So the value 6 is populated for items (which had unique quantities) in the "Total" element. So the total 6 is populated in 1st and 3rd packed items within the second container.

Comment: 2) I mentioned the fourth container as an example. The idea was that I need to compare every "Quantity" in a container to the "Total values from the preceding siblings. So I was looking for a way to do this without having to calculate total again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite challenging.... Here's my XSLT; please note that your XSL processor must support XSLT extensions (exslt) -- if you're using Xalan or Saxon, it will be OK.

Basically, we had to process the Container one after another, and adding information about the Totals already computed. This is done through recursion, which the only way to modify values in XSLT 1.0.

That why you'll find `<xsl:apply-templates select="ex:Container[1]" />` at the very beginning and a `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ex:Container[1]">` to process the next Container, and so on.

The former Total to be compared against a quantity are "stored" in the `computed.totals` parameter, and is filled each time a Container has been processed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
    xmlns:ex="http://www.example.org"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org"
version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ex:Container[1]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:param name="computed.totals"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="curr.total"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="computed.totals" select="$computed.totals"></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="curr.total" select="$curr.total"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ex:Container">
        <!-- A trick to initialize to an empty node-set, see http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xsl-editors/2000JulSep/0068.html -->
        <xsl:param name="computed.totals" select="/@empty-node-set" />

        <!-- Process the current total, taking into accound the totals of preceding siblings -->
        <xsl:variable name="curr.total" select="sum(ex:PackedItem/ex:Quantity[(exsl:node-set($computed.totals)/MyTotal/@value != .) or not(exsl:node-set($computed.totals)/*)])"></xsl:variable>

        <!-- Process current Container elements -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="computed.totals" select="$computed.totals"></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="curr.total" select="$curr.total"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>

        <!-- Process next container, with the updated list of Total already computed -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ex:Container[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="computed.totals">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$computed.totals" />
                <MyTotal>
                    <xsl:attribute name="ContainerID"><xsl:value-of select="ex:ContainerID"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="$curr.total"/></xsl:attribute>
                </MyTotal>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Total')]">
        <xsl:param name="computed.totals"></xsl:param>
        <!-- store the current total of the Container, will be used only when processing the Total -->
        <xsl:param name="curr.total"></xsl:param>

        <xsl:variable name="ContainerID" select="../../ns0:ContainerID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ItemID" select="../ns0:ItemID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Quantity" select="../ns0:Quantity"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="exsl:node-set($computed.totals)/MyTotal[@value = $Quantity]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$Quantity" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="Total" namespace="http://www.example.org">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$curr.total"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are also comments in the stylesheet : let me know if you have further questions.

You can check it works properly here : http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2CH

PS : be careful with the namespaces...

Comment: Thankyou so much for looking into the issue! I am writing the XSLTs in Jdeveloper and this would be deployed to Oracle SOA suite 11g along with my BPEL process. I am not sure if it supports exslt.
I tried to compile the xslt solution you provided in Jdeveloper, but it throws an error saying Transform failed: start of root element expected.

Comment: I further tried to compile the xslt in Stylus studio and I got the following error - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: on line 33 of Sample.xsl:
  XTDE1425: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://exslt.org/common}node-set(). There is no Saxon extension function with the local name node-set

Comment: Thanks Potame. the solution you provided works fine on xalan and saxon processors. Our product however did not support exslt and we have decided to switch to xsl 2.0.

Comment: Sounds all good. With XSLT 2.0, you don't need to use the extensions anymore.

Comment: Yes, we removed the node-set extenstions and the xslt worked just fine.

Comment: Could we enhance this stylesheet to process the same way for all different types of PackedItem (all Packed Items with the same ItemId are considered to be of the same type) in a container.